# MIPS loop on pic32 starter kit

Tags: mips, hardware

I am trying to make a loop to count vowels but it only returns 1.  I am really stuck and a little confused on how to make it count properly

```
la  $a0,prompt1     # print prompt on terminal
jal     printf          # out a string

la  $a0,stringBuffer    # load the address of the stringBuffer
li  $a1,50          # load the length
jal mreads

li $s1, 0
li $s2, 0


la $s0, stringBuffer
loop: lb $a0, ($s0)
jal vowelp
#move $s4, $v0
move $a1, $v0
add $a1, 1
addi $s1, $s1, 1
# j loop




 End:  la $a0, printNumVowels
  li $v0, 4

 jal printf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't seem to be adding anything to $s0, from what I can see you are using that as the register to move through the stringBuffer. You would need to add a byte each time you loop to move characters.